# How can I split this string in Python?

Tags: python

I have a variable `string`.

```
string = '''Layer:defaultRenderLayer
Line 1 text goes here
Line 2 text goes here
Line 3 text goes here
Layer:diffuse
Line 1 text goes here
Line 2 text goes here
Line 3 text goes here
Line 4 text goes here
Line 5 text goes here
Layer:outline
Line 1 text goes here
Line 2 text goes here'''
```

I'm trying to split the string before the text `Layer` like below.

```
string_list = [
    'Layer:defaultRenderLayer\nLine 1 text goes here\nLine 2 text goes here\nLine 3 text goes here',
    'Layer:diffuse\nLine 1 text goes here\nLine 2 text goes here\nLine 3 text goes here\nLine 4 text goes here\nLine 5 text goes here',
    'Layer:outline\nLine 1 text goes here\nLine 2 text goes here'
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import re
print re.split(r"\n(?=Layer)",x)
```

You can use `lookahead` with `re` here to achieve the same.

Output:

```
['Layer:defaultRenderLayer\nLine 1 text goes here\nLine 2 text goes here\nLine 3 text goes here', 
 'Layer:diffuse\nLine 1 text goes here\nLine 2 text goes here\nLine 3 text goes here\nLine 4 text goes here\nLine 5 text goes here', 
 'Layer:outline\nLine 1 text goes here\nLine 2 text goes here']
```

Or you can also use `re.findall`.

```
print re.findall(r"\bLayer\b[\s\S]*?(?=\nLayer\b|$)",x
```

[See Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cD5jK1/7)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `re.split`

```
re.split(r'\s+(?=Layer:)', string)
```

This would do splitting on one or more space characters which exists just before to the string `Layer:`. And note that `\s` would match any kind of space character, ie vertical (*newline,carrage return*) as well as horizontal space character (*whitespace,tabs*).

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = '''Layer:defaultRenderLayer
Line 1 text goes here
Line 2 text goes here
Line 3 text goes here
Layer:diffuse
Line 1 text goes here
Line 2 text goes here
Line 3 text goes here
Line 4 text goes here
Line 5 text goes here
Layer:outline
Line 1 text goes here
Line 2 text goes here'''
>>> re.split(r'\s+(?=Layer:)', string)
['Layer:defaultRenderLayer\nLine 1 text goes here\nLine 2 text goes here\nLine 3 text goes here', 'Layer:diffuse\nLine 1 text goes here\nLine 2 text goes here\nLine 3 text goes here\nLine 4 text goes here\nLine 5 text goes here', 'Layer:outline\nLine 1 text goes here\nLine 2 text goes here']
```

Comment: How can I achieve the same process using re.findall?

Comment: try `re.findall(r'(?s).+?(?=\bLayer:|$)', string)`